# Firebase Query Threads And Deleting Multiple Documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 problems here:

First One:

I want to call `doSomethingOnce()` when deleting all object finish, but i need it to be called only once, so `//Position1` is not the place to call it because it's in a loop, so it'll get called multiple times. `//Position2` doens't work either because from what i understand and tested with logs it gets called before all deleting finish. How to call a function when all the deleting finish?

Second One:

Deleting multiple documents doesn't really work this way. `.delete()` gets executed max 3 times in the loop, so when i have let's say 15 documents, i'd need to call this `for(String id : Ids)` loop with deleting 5 times. How can i delete more that those 3 documents?

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test")
    .whereEqualTo("userID", user.getUid())
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                if(task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                    List<String> Ids = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        Ids.add(documentSnapshot.getId());
                    }

                    for(String id : Ids) {
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test").document(id).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                //Position1
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    //Position2
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Nothing found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Document.delete()` you get back a task. To do certain work when a number of tasks have completed, use `Tasks.whenAll(...)`.

```
Task<Void> Tasks.whenAll(Task...<?> tasks)
```

So something like:

```
ArrayList<Task<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<Void>>();
for(String id : Ids) {
    tasks.add(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("test").document(id).delete());
}
Tasks.whenAll(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I recommend reading Doug's [blog series on "becoming a task master"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html).